# Lazy load routing for component that doesn't have routes. Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm working with component lazy loading of ng2 (latest router). I switched from AsyncRoute (from old route) and now I'm trying to return that functionality.

I have succesfully implemented lazy load via **loadChildren** like in official doc's to some small component that have a routing config and a few childs.

But when I was trying to lazy load component that doesn't have any routing I got an error.

So is it possible to lazy load componnet that doesn't have his own routing? I'll be very appropriate for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## It is not possible to lazy-load module without routing system

Most likely you will receive [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132255/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-lazy-routing-angular-2) error trying to do this.

By specifying `loadChildren` property, you are referencing a module with its own routing subsystem. Given that you'd like to lazy-load components - I suggest you just group them in lazy-loaded module.

Hope it helps!