# Getting Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in angular 4 when enter wrong URL

Tags: angular

I want to redirect user to **page not found** page when user enter workng

This is my **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {path:'products',loadChildren:'app/core/component/frontend/productdetail/productdetail.module#ProductDetailFrontModule'},
        {path:'product-types',loadChildren:'app/core/component/frontend/productdetail/catesubcate.module#CateSubcateComponentModule'},
        {path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/core/component/frontend/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.module#PageNotFoundModule' }
       ]
```

**productdetail.module.ts**

```
const route:Routes =[
{
    path:':slug',
    component:ProductDetailFrontComponent
},{ 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
}]
```

and **catesubcate.module.ts**

```
const route:Routes =[
{
    path:':slug',
    component:CateSubcateComponent
},{
    path:':cate/packages/:slug',
    component:CateSubcateComponent
},{ 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
}]
```

when I enter URL like `http://localhost:4200/products/2-panel-cd-folder`
everything works fine but when I add junk data like `http://localhost:4200/products123/2-panel-cd-folder` i get **Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

same thing happen when with URl `http://localhost:4200/product-types/cd/packages/cd-jewel-case`.

when I enter `http://localhost:4200/product-types123/cd/packages/cd-jewel-case` it give me error, but `http://localhost:4200/product-types/cd/packages123/cd-jewel-case` show me **page not found** page.

when I enter `http://localhost:4200/templates123` instead of `http://localhost:4200/templates` this also show **page not found** page

I've change my code according to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132255` but not helping.

I've search so many thing on net but nothing is working. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132255/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-lazy-routing-angular-2

Comment: I've already tried this. nut not working for me.