# Angular 7 nested lazy loading issue

Tags: angular, angular7-router

I'm using nested lazy loading in my project 
app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './user-panel/user-panel.module#UserPanelModule' },
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProvidButers = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and my user-panel.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserPanelComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
    ]
  }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

But when i use child routing i'm getting this error

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132255/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-lazy-routing-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Lazy routing Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132255/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-lazy-routing-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You please follow the same:-

Solved by deleting unnecessary imports.

Cause of this error you have circular module dependency problem.

For example:

```
'A' module imports (dependent to) 'B' module

'B' module imports (dependent to) 'A' module
```

I suggest you to build a common module that other modules should import the common module.

If you have unnecessary imports delete unnecessary imports.